# Display interleaved image in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rgb

For debugging a embedded image processing software I'm storing the RGB image data in a text file. The content in this file looks like this:

```
0.363281 0.367188 0.339844 0.277344 ...
```

The whole line represents the interleaved RGB image, so the 0.363281 stands for the first red pixel value, 0.367188 for the first green and so on. The pixel datatype is float32.

The target image properties are also know: 3 x 66 x 198 (c x h x w).

How can I display this interleaved image in python with cv2 or matplotlib?
Is there any handy reshape function from numpy that I can use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: see this, it may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443295/combine-3-separate-numpy-arrays-to-an-rgb-image-in-python

Comment: I guess we could close this as duplicate of the linked question?! If not, a clearer problem description would be needed which states in how far this is not helpful.