# Transform 1-D numpy array into 3D RGB array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rgb

What is the best way to transform an 1D array that contains rgb data into a 3D RGB array ?

If the array was in this order, it would be easy, (a single reshape)

> RGB RGB RGB RGB...

However my array is in the form,

> RRRR...GGGG....BBBB

or sometimes even,

> GGGG....RRRR....BBBB (result still should be RGB not GRB)

I could of course derive some Python way to achieve this, I even did try a numpy solution, it works but It is obviously a bad solution, **I wonder what is the best way, maybe a built-in numpy function ?**

**My solution:**

```
for i in range(len(video_string) // 921600 - 1):        # Consecutive frames iterated over.
    frame = video_string[921600 * i: 921600 * (i + 1)]  # One frame
    array = numpy.fromstring(frame, dtype=numpy.uint8)  # Numpy array from one frame.
    r = array[:307200].reshape(480, 640)
    g = array[307200:614400].reshape(480, 640)
    b = array[614400:].reshape(480, 640)
    rgb = numpy.dstack((b, r, g))                       # Bring them together as 3rd dimention
```

Don't let the for loop confuse you, I just have frames concatenated to each other in a string, like a video, which is not a part of the question.

[What did not help me:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443295/combine-3-separate-numpy-arrays-to-an-rgb-image-in-python) In this question, r, g, b values are already 2d arrays so not helping my situation.

**Edit1:** Desired array shape is `640 x 480 x 3`

Comment: How can we reshape to `3D` array without knowing height or width?

Comment: @Divakar Sorry I forgot to mention, I will edit, however it can be seen that a frame is 921600 bytes, divide that with three, we have 307200, which is the product of 640x480.

Answer (score 3):

Reshape to `2D`, transpose and then reshape back to `3D` for `RRRR...GGGG....BBBB` form -

```
a1D.reshape(3,-1).T.reshape(height,-1,3) # assuming height is given
```

Or use reshape with `Fortran` order and then swap axes -

```
a1D.reshape(-1,height,3,order='F').swapaxes(0,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [146]: np.random.seed(0)

In [147]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,2,3)) # original rgb image

In [148]: a1D = np.ravel([a[...,0].ravel(), a[...,1].ravel(), a[...,2].ravel()])

In [149]: height = 4

In [150]: np.allclose(a, a1D.reshape(3,-1).T.reshape(height,-1,3))
Out[150]: True

In [151]: np.allclose(a, a1D.reshape(-1,height,3,order='F').swapaxes(0,1))
Out[151]: True
```

For `GGGG....RRRR....BBBB` form, simply append : `[...,[1,0,2]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my code is performance dependant, so I will test the results and post them in the question, any advices towards performance is also accepted.

Comment: @Rockybilly Keep me posted.