# How to use PIL to merge channel images into one RGB image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, rgba

I've multiple PNG image files, one per channel: red, green, blue and yellow.

How I could merge them into one RBGA image?

So far I tried the following

```
from PIL import Image

red    = Image.open('red.png')
green  = Image.open('green.png')
blue   = Image.open('blue.png')
yellow = Image.open('yellow.png')
rgb = Image.new('RGB', (blue.width, blue.height))
for im in [red, green, blue, yellow]:
    rgb.paste(im, (0, 0))
rgb
```

Obviously it's not working as I'm just overriding the previous image. Any ideas?

Update: thanks to the comments bellow it turns out I can merge the red, green and blue files with:

```
rgb = Image.merge("RGB",(red,green,blue))
```

This is gives something like the follwing result:
[image]

The question now is how I could use the yellow file?

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443295/combine-3-separate-numpy-arrays-to-an-rgb-image-in-python

Comment: Or this one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180534/merge-rgb-band-using-python

Comment: You're aware that yellow is a combination of red and green in the RGB colorspace, right? How should those two components be added to the RGB image being created? What should happen if the total of one of those color components exceeds (also called over-flows) the maximum allowed value it can have?

Comment: @martineau first thanks, I completely missed that yellow is red+green. I have the four files red, green, blue, yellow that's been given, I was just trying to visualize them.

Comment: It's possible to combine them, you just need to define what you want to happen when a red or green component from the yellow image is added to the corresponding component of the image being built and the sum overflows the maximum component value.

Comment: @martineau I uploaded the result when using the red, green, and blue. Can you suggest a way to combine this with yellow to soften the image?

Comment: _Soften_ the image? Please define that better, preferably mathematically in terms of RGB components.

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/d.h.foster/Research/My_PDFs/Foster_Amano_JOSAA_19.pdf